# CacheManger Using Redis Multiplexer with Web.Config Configuration

Tags: c#, asp.net, cachemanager

I need to implement Michael solution using two Cache Instances like he explain in [WhatIfRedisStopsWorkingHowDoIkeepMyAppRunning](http://michaco.net/blog/WhatIfRedisStopsWorkingHowDoIkeepMyAppRunning) but using configuration in web.config.

Finally i only have this line of code

```
var defaultConfig = ConfigurationBuilder.LoadConfiguration("defaultCache");
```

I don`t find how to access to the ConnectionMultiplexer to hook me in the events or do it by config...

Is posible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to configure Redis via app/web.config in [CacheManager](http://cachemanager.michaco.net), 
via [ConnectionString](https://github.com/MichaCo/CacheManager/blob/dev/test/CacheManager.Tests/app.config#L19)

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="redisFromConnectionStrings" connectionString="127.0.0.1:6379,allowAdmin=True,connectTimeout=11,ssl=False,abortConnect=False,connectRetry=10" />
</connectionStrings>
```

or [Redis configuration section](https://github.com/MichaCo/CacheManager/blob/dev/test/CacheManager.Tests/app.config#L21)

```
<cacheManager.Redis xmlns="http://cachemanager.michaco.net/schemas/RedisCfg.xsd">
<connections>
  <connection id="redisAppConfig" allowAdmin="true" password="" ssl="false" sslHost="" connectionTimeout="11" database="3">
    <endpoints>
      <endpoint host="127.0.0.1" port="6379" />
    </endpoints>
  </connection>
</connections>
</cacheManager.Redis>
```

:UPDATE:
There is currently no option to access the connection multiplexer used by CacheManager. 
But you can pass in an existing multiplexer to the configuration.

```
var defaultConfig = ConfigurationBuilder.LoadConfiguration("defaultCache");
var multiplexer = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(...);

defaultConfig = defaultConfig
            .Builder
            .WithRedisConfiguration("redisConfig", multiplexer )
            .Build();
```

Of course you have to instantiate the multiplexer yourself and cannot use the web/app config anymore to configure the Redis part. You'd have to handle that yourself...

Comment: That's not what i mean. I already have CacheManager and Redis configured in web.config. What i need is add a IConnectionMultiplexer to catch the events of the connection configured with web.config.

Comment: @GerardoSeró Ah got it, sorry, you'd have to instantiate the connection multiplexer yourself then and pass that into the configuration part for redis. see update

Comment: Just before your answer I ended up using configuration by code. Thx